# Изменение значений в словаре по повтору ключа в Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, словарь

Вопрос такой. Есть словарь и каждому ключу (строка) соответствует значение (список целых чисел). Можно ли при добавлении в словарь ключа, который уже есть в словаре прибавлять к некоторым числам списка произвольное целое число. Например:

Есть пустой словарь `d = {}`. Есть `for` или `while` и внутри цикла есть условие `if`, при выполнении которого в `d` добавляем пару, где ключ это название города, а значение это список из 5ти целых чисел. Т.е. получается так:

```
d = {'Москва': [1, 1, 0, 0, 3]}
```

Мне нужно, чтобы при попытке добавить в словарь новую пару, ключ которой уже есть в словаре, по этому ключу в списке значений к определенным элементам добавлялись константы.

Т.е. что-то типа того: при попытке добавить вот такой элемент в словарь `d['Москва'] = [1, 1, 0, 0, 3]`, то в паре соответствующей ключу 'Москва' должно произойти следующее:
`d = {'Москва': [1**+1**, 1**+1**, 0, 0, 3**+3**]}` (жирным выделил прибавляющиеся константы.

Причём при различных условиях нужно увеличивать различные элементы списка значений.

Т.е. если идет попытка добавить в словарь такую пару `d['Москва'] = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]`, то происходит следующее:

```
d = {'Москва': [1**+1**, 1, 0, 0**+1**, 3]}
```

Comment: Приведите конкретные примеры исходного словаря, что вы хотите добавить и что должно получиться в итоге.

Comment: Что значит - к "некоторым числам"? По какому признаку определять - к какому числу списка нужно прибавлять единицу, а к какому - не нужно? И что значит "при добавлении в словарь ключа"? Ключ нельзя добавить сам по себе, он всегда идёт в паре со значением. Если мы сохраняем существующее значение, увеличив его некоторые элементы на единицу, то значит ли это, что добавляемое значение нужно просто проигнорировать? Ну и последний вопрос - а вы уверены, что при наличии нетривиальной кастомной логики на добавление элемента вам действительно стоит использовать словарь, а не отдельный класс?